# How do I fix this leak in my sink supply plumbing?

Tags: kitchens, copper

The leak seems to be in the coupling.  I can’t tell how to remove coupling from the hose and if it is an easy replace.  The tap leaks when tap is turned on only and it is the hot water hose

The coupling looks like it’s come loose, so I'm not sure if it just needs another coupling or more work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It was most likely someone DIYing it, but it really doesn't matter _who_ made that catastrophe of a "fix", it's now up to you to to get it fixed. 1) stop using water at this sink until you get it repaired. 2) Remove the tape or whatever that black wrap is to see what you've actually got under there, then get us a good pic of the actual fittings underneath. From that, someone will be able to guide you to the _proper_ solution.

Comment: Hi there.  I’ll get some more photos for you asap.  Thank you for getting back to me so quickly

Comment: While you [edit] your pics into the question, you may want to shift the wording to focus on "how to fix this" instead of "who made this mistake".

Comment:  that bad eh?   Ok so that black piece of plastic is a coupler not tape. The leak is at the top of the bizarre looking coupler

Comment: Well, the answer to your question, as asked is, "We don't know". So focusing on "how do I fix" this is more useful for you. As far as that connector goes, I haven't a clue, but I'm sure someone will be able to help you soon...

Comment: When I get home I will remove the coupler and take more photos.

Comment: Carefully bend those two supply lines away from the coupling to give you a bit more room to fix/replace the coupling.  It appears to be incorrectly installed.

Comment: Thank you.   Could you recommend a coupling to replace

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the hot water supply hose, looks like a hose for a pull-out faucet or separate sprayer, so I expect it will leak cold water just fine. The new pictures are a little better, but one of that level of detail from the direction of the original "too small to see anythng" picture might help. Carefully bending the supply lines away as Jack suggests would also help.